# Make checkboxes required after a value of a selectbox has been chosen (jquery-validate)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have seen a few answers already but when i try them they do not work.

What i try to do is when i have selected test1 in the selectbox, with value 8, then the checkboxes are required to be checked, or atleast one.

When i have selected test2, then those checkboxes are not required to be checked.

example:

```
<form id="submit" method="post" action="" name="postform"/>
<select name="type"/>
<option>Select type</option>
<option value="8">test1</option>
<option value="12">test2</option>
</select>

<input name="group[]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
<input name="group[]" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
<input name="group[]" type="checkbox" value="3"/>
</form>
```

and here the jquery validation:

```
$("#submit").validate({
    rules: {
        type: "required",
        group: {
            required: {
                depends: function() {
                    if ($('#type').val() == 8) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        group: "groups are required."
    }
});
```

For the groups, i also tried without the [] and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This it will add required attribute in every input checkbox on select dropdown value --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dropdown').change(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr("required", "true");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: maybe i was not clear enough, sorry i'll try better. So when i selected item one and then press submit, it must say that i need to select a checkbox before submitting can be done. However, when i selected item2, then i can submit without checking a box.

Comment: yes its working because when u select select box it will add required attribute in checkbox and then validate method will automatic work for all required fields when u submit a form..

Comment: Update: It works when i just have one checkbox. But these checkboxes comes out of an array and more can be selected. How come it does not work on more checkboxes?

Comment: No Kohlzz it will work for all checkboxes it`s not fixed it will work for all .. u can try ....